# Single Page Application - Frontend independent of backend?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

I've done some research and I've noticed that in a lot of examples Symfony2/AngularJS apps the frontend and backend are combined; for example, views use Twig.

I'd always thought that it's possible (and common practice) to create the frontend and backend separately and just join them by API. In that case if I want to  change a PHP framework I will can do it without any problems and it will be enough to keep API.

So what are the best practices for doing it? It would be great if you could explain it to me and even greater if you just give me a link to good example on github or something.

Comment: You are correct,  your index should be your only html that was generated/interpreted by the server.  The rest of your html,css,js is static and your endpoint data is simply passed as JSON.

Comment: @Dylan you can also avoid returning the index too. See my answer

Comment: Also Symfony2/AngularJS has a few caveats which may be confusing your understanding of it.  Things like Twig and angular will clash over the variable syntax {{}}.  So there are a lot of tutorials on the issue and it's not exactly about best practice or anything.

Comment: You should only make an API, so front-end and back-end are totally separated and independent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have been developing some projects using the same approach. Not only I think it doesn't have any "side effect", but the solution is very elegant too.
We usually create the backend in Node.js, and it is just an API server (not necessarily entirely REST-compliant). We then create another, separate web application for the frontend, written entirely in HTML5/JavaScript (with or without Angular.js). The API server *never* returns any HTML, just JSON! Not even an index structure.

There are lots of benefits:

- The code is very clean and elegant. Communication between the frontend and the backend follow standardized methods. The server exposes some API's, and the client can use them freely.
- It makes it easier to have different teams for the frontend and the backend, and they can work quite freely without interfering with each other. Designers, which usually have limited coding skills, appreciate this too.
- The frontend is just a static HTML5 app, so it can (and we often did) easily be hosted on a CDN. This means that your servers will never have to worry about static contents at all, and their load is reduced, saving you money. Users are happier too, as CDNs are usually very fast for them.

Some hints that I can give you based on our experience:

- The biggest issue is with authentication of users. It's not particularly complicated, but you may want to implement authentication using for example protocols like OAuth 2.0 for your internal use. So, the frontend app will act as a OAuth client, and obtains an auth token from the backend. You may also want to consider moving the authentication server (with OAuth) on another separate resource from the API server.
- If you host the webapp on a different hostname (e.g. a CDN) you may need to deal with CORS, and maybe JSONP.
- The language you write the backend in is not really important. We have done that in PHP (including Laravel), even though we got the best results with using Node.js. For Node.js, we published our [boilerplate on GitHub](https://github.com/EgoAleSum/restify-boilerplate), based on RestifyJS

I asked some questions in the past you may be interested in:

- [Web service and API: "chicken or egg"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337160/web-service-and-api-chicken-or-egg)
- [Security of an API server: login with password and sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827158/security-of-an-api-server-login-with-password-and-sessions)

Comment: Thank you, I'll read what you give me.

But I have one more question. Are there any rationale behind mixing Symfony2 and AngularJS ? Maybe if somebody wants to use Angular only in some part of application like pagination or adding comments?

Comment: Angular is more powerful to create entire web apps that are MVC based. I don't see why you should limit it to specific components.  Anyway, the choice is yours :)

Comment: with Symfony2 it is super easy to build an API, and implement it in AngularJS, so the combination of these two monster frameworks is very rational indeed, but limiting Angular to specific components is not, you'd get the job done in jQuery much faster.